# Angular change default value of select from filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box which is populated with some data from my controller. When an input value changes the contents of the select box should be filtered and a default value should be assigned based on the is default property of the data object.

Is there any way this can be done using angular directives or would it need to be done as a custom filter function doing something along the lines of

```
angular.forEach(vm.data,function(item){
if (vm.q == item.someId && item.isDefault) {
vm.result = item.value;
}
});
```

My html looks something like

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.q">
  <select ng-options="item.value as item.description for item in vm.data | filter:{someId:vm.q}" ng-model="vm.result"></select>
</div>
```

and my controller looks like:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myApp',[]);
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('ctrl',ctrl);

    function ctrl()
    {
        var vm = this;

        vm.data = [
            {
                someId: '1',
                description: 'test1',
                value: 100,
                isDefault: true
            },
            {
                someId: '2',
                description: 'test2',
                value: 200,
                isDefault: false
            },
            {
                someId: '3',
                description: 'test3',
                value: 100,
                isDefault: true
            },        
        ];
    }
})();
```

See my plunkr demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RDhQWQcHFMQJvwOyHI4r?p=preview

Desired behaviour:
1) Enter 1 into text box
2) List should be filtered to 2 items
3) Select box should pre-select item 1 based on property isDefault set to true

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just tried your plnkr sample and it seems to filter properly, still not quite sure what you want at the end? could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Hi i've added some desired behaviour to the description which should be clearer about what I was trying to say

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you include some 3rd party library, like [lodash](https://lodash.com/), into your project to make working with arrays/collections that much easier.

After that you could add `ng-change` directive for your `input`.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.q" ng-change="vm.onChange(vm.q)">
```

And the actual `onChange` function in the controller

```
vm.onChange = function(id) {
  var item = _.findWhere(vm.data, { someId: id, isDefault: true });
  vm.result = item ? item.value : null;
};
```

And there you have it.